# Pydantic error when reading data from JSON

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I am writing code, which loads the data of a JSON file and parses it using Pydantic.

Here is the Python code:

```py
import json
import pydantic
from typing import Optional, List


class Car(pydantic.BaseModel):
    manufacturer: str
    model: str
    date_of_manufacture: str
    date_of_sale: str
    number_plate: str
    price: float
    type_of_fuel: Optional[str]
    location_of_sale: Optional[str]


def load_data() -> None:
    with open("./data.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        cars: List[Car] = [Car(**item) for item in data]
        print(cars[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_data()
```

And here is the JSON data:

```json
[
    {
        "manufacturer": "BMW",
        "model": "i8",
        "date_of_manufacture": "14/06/2021",
        "date_of_sale": "19/11/2022",
        "number_plate": "ND21WHP",
        "price": "100,000",
        "type_of_fuel": "electric",
        "location_of_sale": "Leicester, England"
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Audi",
        "model": "TT RS",
        "date_of_manufacture": "22/02/2019",
        "date_of_sale": "12/08/2021",
        "number_plate": "LR69FOW",
        "price": "67,000",
        "type_of_fuel": "petrol",
        "location_of_sale": "Manchester, England"
    }
]
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
File "pydantic\main.py", line 342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Car
price value is not a valid float (type=type_error.float)
```

I have tried adding `.00` to the end of the price strings but I get the same error.

Comment: That's not a float, that's a string, and a string that contains a comma.  You either need to declare it as a `str`, or change the entries to `"price": 67000,` with no quotes and no commas.

Comment: "100,000" is not a valid number because of the `,` separator. Can't you have the source of the data provide it with correct numbers  - and numbers, not strings - for prices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the default Pydantic validator for `float` simply [tries to coerce](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/validators.py#L152) the string value to `float` (as @Paul mentioned). And `float("100,000")` leads to a `ValueError`.

I am surprised no one suggested this, but if you don't control the source JSON data, you can easily solve this issue by writing your own little [validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) to properly format the string (or parse the number properly yourself):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Car(BaseModel):
    manufacturer: str
    model: str
    date_of_manufacture: str
    date_of_sale: str
    number_plate: str
    price: float
    type_of_fuel: Optional[str]
    location_of_sale: Optional[str]

    @validator("price", pre=True)
    def adjust_number_format(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return v.replace(",", "")
        return v
```

The `pre=True` is important to make the adjustment *before* the default field validator receives the value. I purposefully did it like this to show that you don't need to convert the `str` to a `float` yourself, but you could of course do that too:

```py
...
    @validator("price", pre=True)
    def parse_number(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return float(v.replace(",", ""))
        return v
```

Both of these work and require no changes in the JSON document.

---

Finally, if you have (or anticipate to have in the future) multiple number-like fields and know that all of them may cause such problems with weirdly formatted strings, you could generalize that validator like this: (different class for demo pruposes)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.fields import ModelField


class Car2(BaseModel):
    model: str
    price: float
    year: int
    numbers: list[float]

    @validator("*", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def format_number_string(cls, v: object, field: ModelField) -> object:
        if issubclass(field.type_, (float, int)) and isinstance(v, str):
            return v.replace(",", "")
        return v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    car = Car2.parse_obj({
        "model": "foo",
        "price": "100,000",
        "year": "2,010",
        "numbers": ["1", "3.14", "10,000"]
    })
    print(car)  # model='foo' price=100000.0 year=2010 numbers=[1.0, 3.14, 10000.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the decimal comma `,` to a `_` and keep the string.

Pydantic is taking care of the str to float conversion then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes around the numbers since they are being interpreted as strings.

`"price": "100,000"` should be:
`"price": 100000`

Comment: Pydantic coerces strings to numbers by default. That is _not_ the problem here. The problem is the _format_ of those number strings. Specifically the `,`. Removing that or replacing it with `_` would already solve the issue.